# Record webm from canvas using MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, mediastream

I'm trying to create a .webm file from a canvas. To do this I'm using `captureStream` and `MediaRecorder`. However, I'm having issues as the `ondataavailable` event only gets fired when the MediaRecorder is stopped, and the event data it contains is `size` 0.

I've been following these guides to help implement this:

- https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-record/
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder

Here are the relevant parts of my code (you can see the [full code](https://github.com/peterjgordon/waterpipe.js/blob/master/waterpipe.js) too):

On init:

```
this.displayCanvas = this.$element.find('canvas')[0];
this.bufferCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
this.backgroundCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
this.context = this.displayCanvas.getContext("2d");
this.bufferContext = this.bufferCanvas.getContext("2d");
this.backgroundContext = this.backgroundCanvas.getContext("2d");
// recording stream
this.stream = this.displayCanvas.captureStream(25);
console.log("Stream started: ", this.stream);
```

Drawing:

```
this.context.drawImage(this.backgroundCanvas, 0, 0);
this.context.drawImage(this.bufferCanvas, this.scrollOffset, -400);
```

Capture start:

```
var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
this.recording = true;

recordedChunks = [];
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream, options);
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.captureDataAvailable;
mediaRecorder.start(100);
```

On data available:

```
captureDataAvailable: function(event) {
    console.log('data available: ');
    console.log(event.data);
    if(event.data.size > 0) {
        console.log('writing');
        recordedChunks.push(event.data);
    }
}
```

Capture finished:

```
mediaRecorder.stop();
console.log(recordedChunks.length);
var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {type: 'video/webm'});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.style.display = 'none';
a.href = url;
a.download = 'Waterpipe-' + Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000) + '.webm';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
//window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
//document.body.removeChild(a);

this.recording = false;
```

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Call the finish part on the onstop handler of your MediaRecorder.

Comment: My issue turned out to be that when the canvas changes size, I had to reopen the window. Just reloading the page didn't seem to be enough. I also took your advice @Kaiido, thanks!